# Comparing Numbers against Strings in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which returns the following sample data :-

```
SELECT * FROM VW_STATUSNEW

ID STATUS_1 STATUS_2
1  FAIL     1
2  FAIL     NULL
3  1        NULL
4  NULL     2
5  2        2
6  2        FAIL
7  NULL     NULL
```

Is it possible in Oracle to return all rows where STATUS_1 and STATUS_2 do not match. So, using the data above, the required results are :-

```
ID STATUS_1 STATUS_2
1  FAIL     1
2  FAIL     NULL
3  1        NULL
4  NULL     2
6  2        FAIL
```

The issue seems to be with comparing the word FAIL with a number, and catering for NULLs.

Comment: what if both columns are NULL?

Comment: Why do u think  it fails with a numeric and alphabet string?  It does not since neither  datatypes are  numeric. Please understand the issue and  don't blindly assume things..problem is only with null comparisons, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM VW_STATUSNEW
WHERE STATUS_1 <> STATUS_2
OR (STATUS_1 IS NULL AND STATUS_2 IS NOT NULL)
OR (STATUS_1 IS NOT NULL AND STATUS_2 IS NULL);
```

**OR**

```
SELECT *
FROM VW_STATUSNEW
WHERE STATUS_1 <> STATUS_2
OR NOT (STATUS_1 IS NULL AND STATUS_2 IS NULL)
```

**Output**

```
ID  STATUS_1    STATUS_2
1   FAIL        1
2   FAIL        (null)
3   1           (null)
4   (null)      2
6   2           FAIL
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3694b/5

Answer (score 2):

The two statuses have the same type (there are strings in both columns). so comparison shouldn't be a problem.  Here is one way:

```
SELECT *
FROM VW_STATUSNEW
WHERE (status1 <> status2) OR
      (not (status1 is null and status2 is null)) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the few cases where `DECODE` is still useful, because according to decode, NULL is equal to null.

```
select * 
  from VW_STATUSNEW
 where decode(status_1, status_2, 1, 0) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
SELECT 
  ID 
  ,STATUS_1 
  ,STATUS_2 
FROM VW_STATUSNEW 
where NVL(STATUS_1, '0') != NVL(STATUS_2, '0')
```

Comment: it won't work NVL(null, '') will give you null and null can't be compared

Comment: I'm not sure this would work the way you want it to - the empty string is equivalent to NULL in Oracle

Comment: Run this and check `SELECT NVL(NULL,'') FROM DUAL`

Comment: What if `STATUS_1` is `0` and `STATUS_2` is `NULL`? They shouldn't match, but with your query they will.

Answer (score 0):

```
with testtab as (select 'Fail' "STAT1", '1' "STAT2" from dual
union all select 'Fail', null from dual
union all select '1', null from dual
union all select null, '2' from dual
union all select '2', '2' from dual
union all select '2', 'FAIL' from dual
union all select null, null from dual)
select * from testtab
where nvl(STAT1,-1) != nvl(STAT2,-1);
```

returns

```
Stat1   Stat2 
Fail    1
Fail    null
1       null
null    2
2       FAIL
```

Stat1 = status_1 in your example.

`nvl(value, altValue)` returns `altValue` if `value` is null